# Symantec VPN equivalent for Linux client

Tags: linux, vpn, symantec

I have a customer that I connect to via Symantec Client VPN  (v9 if that matters) on Windows.  I'm doing some tidying up and was wondering if there was a simple way to be able to connect to the same vpn endpoint from a Linux desktop.

Unfortunately I know nothing about their endpoint other than it being a Symantec product, so I guess the basic version of my question is:

"accepting that mileage may vary is it generally possible to authenticate with an Symantec vpn server from a Linux desktop"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question all boils down to the specific protocol that the end point is implementing. Generally speaking if its even a remotely standards compliant IPSEC server you will be able to connect to it with one of the available Linux front ends, FreeSwan / Raccoon. If its Cisco vpn client compatible you may have luck with vpnc, either way the best thing to do would be to find out the settings of the client end endpoint and then go from there. Of course if you get desperate you may just be able to run the vpn client through a virtual machine.